# Struggling to web scape data with Java (Jsoup)

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm currently attempting to scrape data from an Nrl Fantasy Stats website (https://fantasy.nrl.com/stats-centre) but am unable to drill down into the table and rows and extract any data at all.

To be clear, I'm attempting to pull sports player data from the table on the website such as name, position, avg fantasy points, etc.

Someone I spoke to said I should go into Developer Tools > Network and then filter for XHR to do it. I've tried doing this but haven't been successful at all so far. I've also attempting to access CSS elements within the HTML to pull the data but haven't had any luck with that either.

If anyone could provide me some further guidance I'd be very grateful!

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It's always a good idea to show the code you used to solve your problem. Have also a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to use https://tds-nrl-data.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/data/nrl/coach/players.json in order to scrape players table instead https://fantasy.nrl.com/stats-centre.

Comment: I wasn't aware of any JSON data for nrl stats. Thanks for your input.